# Geometric interpretation of adding dependence on a otherwise constant in a vector field.

Tags: calculus, geometry, vectors

So if i have

$$ \vec{u} = \Omega r \vec{e_{\theta}}$$

Now if i take the curl

$$\omega = 2\Omega\vec{e_z}$$

This is what we expect, we have a "rotating flow".
Who's curl would be pointing in the z direction.

Now when I make $\Omega = \Omega(z)$

I get

$$\omega = -\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial z}r\vec{e_r}  + 2\Omega\vec{e_z}$$

I can understand that if we were to fix our r and move up the z axis we are no longer going to have the same "angular velocity". For some reason I can't quite string a sentence together to interpret this extra term, geometrically speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To visualize it, you can take a look at a point, say $\theta = 0$ and $ r= constant $

So this is a view from x+ direction towards the origin.

The velocity distribution along the z axis is not even if $\Omega (z)$ is not constant. This will produce a non-zero component of swirl in x direction or in r direction. This is the extra term in your post.

Comment: what is swirl? Sorry, I have never heard that term before :)